# Parse xml file with same tag multiple times iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

In my application, I have a tag  multiple times. I'm using xml parser. I'm taking a corresponding element with similar name as the one in xml file in my class. So in case of:

```
 <photo>abc</photo>
 <photo>def</photo>
```

What I get in photo element of my class is the second element i.e def, as the first one gets overwritten as there's only one photo element in my class. My question is am I wrong in taking similar elements in class as in case of xml? Is there any better method or a better parser? Or I'm on right path and have to do this manually by setting some flags etc?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: How do you want to handle this case? Create several photo elements, always use the first, ...?

Comment: No, I want to get them all in an array. I solved this by making the "photo" element in my class as nsmutablearray. Thanx for trying to help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you try to parse the contents of an XML to match to properties on an object using NSXMLParser.

If it is valid to encounter multiple `photo` tags in your XML then either you need a strategy to know which one will map to a property, or convert your property to an `NSArray` and add the results as they come.

If it is not a valid case, you could check if you set the property earlier and raise an error, or just override it (as you do) and call it "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 0):

There are many parsers there that can handle your issue (e.g. XPathQuery, TouchXML etc.).

I don't think that there is a need to reinvent the wheel - use one of the existing parsers.